# How to convert http://www.abc.org:8080/index.jsp into http://www.abc.org/index.jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

How I can convert `http://www.abc.org:8080/index.jsp` to `http://www.abc.org/index.jsp?`

is there any configuration in `server.xml` file?

i have tested at `http://www.abc.org:8080/index.jsp` and this is working.

Comment: Which Servlet container do you use?

Comment: You need **something** running on port 80; either change the port from 8080 to 80, or set up another listener on 80 with a redirect to 8080.

Comment: tomcat7 and it is shared hosting plan.

Comment: they did n't change the port because of shared hosting. any other process.